# Extract rows from list given two criteria

Tags: python, list, extract

What I have:
I have a list of lists, `nodes`. Each list has the following structure:

```
nodes = [[ID, number 1, number 2, number 3],[...]]
```

I also have two other lists of lists called `sampleID` and `sampleID2` where each list may only have single data equal to an `ID` number which belongs to a subset of the total `IDs` contained in `nodes`:

```
sampleID = [[IDa],[...]]
sampleID2 = [[IDb],[...]], len(sampleID) + len(sampleID2) <= len(nodes)
```

In some cases these lists can also be like:

```
sampleID = [[IDa1,IDa2, IDa3,...],[...]]
```

What I want:
Given the above three lists I'd like to obtain in a fast way a fourth list which contains the lists where `IDi==ID`, i=a,b:

```
extractedlist = [[ID, number 1, number 2, number 3],[...]], len(extractedlist) = len(sampleID) + len(sampleID2)
```

My code:
Very basic, it works but it takes a lot of time to compute:

```
import itertools
for line in nodes[:]:
    for line2,line3 in itertools.izip(sampleID[:],sampleID2[:]):
        for i in range(0,len(line2)):
            if line2[i]==line[0]:
                extractedlist.append([line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3]])
        for j in range(0,len(line3)):
            if line3[j]==line[0]:
                extractedlist.append([line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not understand your problem well but this is what i understand :P

```
node = [ .... ]
sampleID = [ .... ]
sampleID2 = [ .... ]
final_ids = []
[final_ids.extend(list_item) for list_item in sampleID]
[final_ids.extend(list_item) for list_item in sampleID2]

extractedlist = []

for line in nodes:
    if line[0] in final_ids:
        extractedlist.append(line)
```

hope this is what you need.
Else just add original input-list and result-list in question so i can understand what you want to do :)

Comment: It works. However, if instead of `sampleID = [[IDa],[...]]` the `sampleID` is `sampleID = [[IDa1,IDa2, IDa3,...],[...]]`, would it also work? `sampleID` can have in general one ID per row but in some cases it may have up to 16 per row. Thanks

Comment: yes it is works because all values from list sampleID are extending final_ids so any type list in sampleID would work.
if SampleId is like this

 `sampleID = [[IDa1,IDa2, IDa3,...Id16],[Id17,Id18],[ID19],[Id20,Id21, ... Id31] ]`

Then also its going t work :)